# Should i go for a Server or Desktop for file sharing

Tags: file-sharing, linux-server

So i live in Tanzania where internet is very expensive at low speeds.

i.e. My current plan is 5Mbps for $60 per month.

I have 4 heavy users who mostly download torrents and large files.

My connection doesn't seem to perform well with my current Load, i am not willing to spend more money to increase the speed.

Fast forward
I have a VPs at contabo(a german based vps provider) . I have a speed of 80Mbps in my VPS

My current solution is to build a simple web App , the App will do the following

1. The user will access my app by visiting www.myApp.net/download?link=somelink.zip
2. The app will send a request to the server to download the file .
3. The server will download the file, when download is complete, the server will upload the file to my home server
4. I can access the file on my local server without any need for an internet connection.

Below is How long the whole process takes to download a file of size 10Gb

With my Local connection it will take **4hours** to download a 10Gb file size

With my server approach the file will only take **17minutes** to download

**Local Server SetUp**
I have two options, one is buying a cheap entry level  refubrished server with 4GB Ram, quadcore processor,  In Tanzania this server will cost roughly $500

another option is to setup a desktop and install linux server in it ,.. A good refubrished desktop with 8GB Ram, 3.0Ghz quadcore processor will cost around $200

I dont really mind about Hard drive size because i can always scale up and down as my storage needs change..

My question is, can a powerful desktop computer, with the above specs operate well as a server for my outlined requirement ??

I really need to know if saving money and buying a desktop instead of a server will be really worth it in the long run..

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that your internet is always going to be the bottleneck. Although the VPS can download it quickly, it cannot send the file quickly to your home.

All you are doing is adding a second download, and thus adding more delays.

The only benefit of using your VPS as intermediary is that you have control over the speed so your internet does not slow down to a crawl, and it will also help securing files quicker because with torrents, a torrent may go away if you can't get it fast enough.

But even then, when the file is downloaded, it is still on your VPS and in order to get that file to your home server, it will be uploaded there slowly because your internet simply is not fast enough.

As for your local server requirements, it does not really matter if you use actual server hardware or desktop hardware. Yes, server hardware will increase its performance because it is geared to be in a server, but it is often geared for many many users to use the server, where in your situation it will not have many users. For that reason a desktop pc will work well enough as a server, although it will not allow you to do much.

For example, I use an intel NUC pc as my server. I run a DC on it and an RDS server. Performance is not quick, but fast enough for one user (me), and I store all my files there. In your situation something similar will work. Depending on what you do with the server, RAM is preferable. Keep in mind that a server has other type of ram compared to a desktop, but again, in your case a desktop pc will work well enough for a server.

Comment: thanks for your input.. How much drop in speed should i expect when my vps with 80Mbps is uploading data to my local server with an up/down speed of 50Mbps ??

Comment: Your post tells you that your internet speed is only 5 MBps. So that is going to be the speed you'll receive. It is physically impossible to transfer data faster than the slowest connection, so everything will queue up on the server. If you upgrade your local internet to 50Mbps, then that will be the highest speed possible.